# how does it work internally

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

```
var user = userContext.Users.First(u => u.Id == 1);
user.Name = "John";
userContext.SaveChanges();
```

How does `EF` know that only Name column was changed and hence create the SQL Query to update it?

How does `EF` keep track of the entities?

Does it keep a copy of the entity in memory after getting it from database, and then compare  it with the modified entity from the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes. EF keeps "original" copy of data read from database. You can read more on [change tracking on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896269%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks, so you in memory there will be the modified object AND original object?  I wonder how does that work for a big number of rows. but I guess there's no other way for orm to keep track of changes

Comment: You would not normally modify huge numbers of entities at once. The usual workflow involves displaying large numbers of records and letting the user choose one to modify and update. It might be useful to have different operations on your DAL: simple "read" that uses "no tracking" option and "read for update" that reads with change tracking enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework has the option to generate a Proxy class for each model that tracks changes. Essentially, it wraps the object with self-tracking properties.

Basically, you can envision it implemented something like this (I'm not sure of the actual internals but this should help a little with the *theory*, you can decompile if you want to see *exactly* how it's done):

```
internal List<string> ChangedFields = new List<string>();

private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set {
        ChangedFields.Add("Name");
        _name = value;
    }
}
```

Obviously with this replicated for each field, each field you make a change to is then tracked in `ChangedFields`.

Again, that is purely for illustrative purposes of how it may work using properties with explicit `get`/`set`, *not* specifically how Entity Framework does it.

Comment: but sometimes you do not get a proxy, but the non-proxied instance. how does it work in this case?

Comment: @OpCoder If you were to disable the proxy generation, the backing `ObjectContext` actually does the tracking. When you retrieve the object from the database using the context, it stores a copy of the object, and upon saving uses `DetectChanges()` to see if there are any differences, and what needs saving.